# Using IOC in a remoting scenario

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, remoting, castle-windsor

I'm struggling with getting IOC to work in a remoting scenario. I have my application server set up to publish Services (SingleCall) which are configured via XML.

This works just like this as we all know:

```
RemotingConfiguration.Configure(ConfigFile, true);
```

lets say my service looks like that (pseudocode)

```
public class TourService : ITourService
{
    IRepository _repository;
    public TourService()
    {
         _repository = new SqlServerRepository();   
    }
}
```

But what I rather would like to have sure looks like this:

```
public class TourService : ITourService
{
    IRepository _repository;
    public TourService(IRepository repository)
    {
         _repository = repository;   
    }
}
```

On the client side we do something like that (pseudocode again):

```
(ITourService)Activator.GetObject(ITourService, tcp://server/uri);
```

This prompts the server to create a new instance of my TourService class...

However this doesn't seem to work out well because the .NET Remoting Infrastructure want's to know the **type** it should publish but I would rather like to point it to the way how it could retrieve the **object** it should publish. In other words, route it through the IOC process pipe of - let's say windsor castle - for example.

Currently I'm a bit lost on that task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to be using windsor castle there is a Remoting Facility that will help you out. Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/remoting/index.html).

Comment: Thx, I have read the documentation carefully and would just like to make sure that I am getting it right. In my case, where I need to have the server to build the services with constructor injection, only the 3rd scenario will work out, right? 

http://www.castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/remoting/containersconnected.html