# using ninject with a remoting server

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ninject, remoting

I have a class `Server` that implements interface `IServer` that is accessible using .net remoting (i have no chioce on the matter JICYAW).

internally this server uses other classes to implement logic and data access.

this `server` class has constructor injected dependencies that it needs to do its job.

when a client calls in (per call) the remoting framework will instatiate a `Server` instance using a parameterless constructor and not (of course) using Ninject.

how can i get Ninject to be the one in charge for new'ing up the class ?

i have seen this similar SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458271/using-ioc-in-a-remoting-scenario) but this isnt relevant for Ninject.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a service facade that will be called by the client. This facade will internally call your container to resolve the real service. For instance:

```
public class ServiceFacade : IService
{
    private readonly IService service;

    // default constructor
    public ServiceFacade()
    {
        this.service = YourContainer.Current.Resolve<IService>();
    }

    void IService.ServiceOperation()
    {
        this.service.ServiceOperation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! simple and clean. but is there a way to do this wothout adding another layer ?

Comment: Having used Remoting, I suggest the extra layer for the proxy is worth the effort. Otherwise, using an injector like @Steven suggests below is a good way to go.

Answer (score 0):

What might work is to intercept the calls to those objects using a proxy and forward the calls to the real object. Note that I'm not very experienced with this, so I'm not sure if this actually works, but here goes:

```
public class DependencyInjectionProxy : RealProxy
{
    private object realInstance;

    public DependencyInjectionProxy(Type classToProxy, 
        object realInstance) : base(classToProxy)
    {
        this.realInstance = realInstance;
    }

    public static T MakeProxy<T>(T realInstance)
    {
        return (T)(new DependencyInjectionProxy(typeof(T),
            realInstance).GetTransparentProxy());
    }

    public override IMessage Invoke(IMessage msg)
    {
        if (msg is IMethodCallMessage)
        {
            var message = (IMethodCallMessage)msg;

            object value = message.MethodBase.Invoke(
                this.realInstance, message.Args);

            Console.WriteLine(value);

            return new ReturnMessage(value, null, 0, null, message);
        }

        return msg;
    }
}
```

This works when you do something like this:

```
var container = new YourContainer();

container.RegisterSingle<IService, Service>();

IService proxy = DependencyInjectionProxy.MakeProxy<IService>(
    container.Resolve<IService>());

proxy.SomeMethod();
```

This works great, but to be honest, I have no idea how to configure this in a way that you can intercept incoming calls this way. Somewhere you need to register your `DependencyInjectionProxy`, but that's where my experience with remoting stops :-)

Comment: Thansk again Steven, after witnessing this, i think i`ll take neotapir`s advice here an go for your first advice. (i think a custom server message sink may be the missing link here)